# How to access kubernetes namespace from a yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

Im trying to create yaml for deployment with kubernetes. I am using a same script for different environment, which is separated with namespace. Now, I need to access the namespace name within the deployment yaml, such as

```
"name":"$(namespace)"
```

in the yaml file. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*edit* sorry, I may have misunderstood your question: if you want access to the current namespace in which the Pod is running, you can inject that into its environment via an [`env: valueFrom:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#envvarsource-v1-core) construct, described in greater detail [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/):

```
env:
- name: MY_NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

---

Omit the `namespace:` from the yaml and provide it to `kubectl` as `kubectl --namespace=foo1 create -f my-thing.yaml` (assuming, of course, you're using `kubectl`; the idea behind the answer is the same, just the mechanics will change if using a different method)

You can also specify the default namespace in `~/.kube/config` in the context, and address it that way: `kubectl --context=server-foo1` which allows associating different credentials with the different namespaces, too. They all boil down to the same effect in the end, it's just a matter of which is the most convenient for your case.

The most extreme(?) form is that you can also have multiple configs and switch between them via `env KUBECONFIG=$TMPDIR/foo1.yaml kubectl create -f my-thing.yaml`